# Can I make a installer with NSIS which installs DLL with new name?

Tags: nsis

I want to make installer that copies and register (regsvr32) a.dll

When installer failed to overwrite a.dll, (because in-use, ... etc)
I want to copy a.dll as a0.dll and register it.

Can I do that with NSIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should do it.

```
section ""
File a.dll
execwait "Regsvr32 /s a.dll"
IfErrors 0 noError
Rename a.dll a0.dll
execwait "Regsvr32 /s a0.dll"
noError:
sectionEnd
```